# pandas merge rows based on grouping

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
col1    col2    col3
a       1       a
a       98      xx
a       99      xy
b       1       a
b       2       b
b       3       c
b       8       xx
b       9       xy
```

I need to merge rows where in `col3` = `xx` and `xy`, which are grouped by `col1`, hence the resulting dataframe looks like:

```
col1    col2    col3
a       1       a
a       98      xz
b       1       a
b       2       b
b       3       c
b       8       xz
```

Is there a simple way of doing this `pandas`?

Comment: So you only have two special values `xx` and `xy`. And they always are replaced (hardcoded) by `xz`?

Comment: Yes, let's assume that

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
df.groupby([df.col1,df.col3.replace({'xx':'xz','xy':'xz'})]).col2.first().reset_index()
Out[29]: 
  col1 col3  col2
0    a    a     1
1    a   xz    98
2    b    a     1
3    b    b     2
4    b    c     3
5    b   xz     8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach with `drop_duplicates`:

```
# xx and xy
s = df.col3.isin(['xx','xy']);

(df.assign(col3=lambda x: np.where(s, 'xz', x['col3']), # replace xx and xy with xz
           mask=s,                                      # where xx and xy
           block=(~s).cumsum())                         # block of xx and xy
   .drop_duplicates(['col1','mask','block'])
   .drop(['mask','block'], axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2 col3
0    a     1    a
1    a    98   xz
3    b     1    a
4    b     2    b
5    b     3    c
6    b     8   xz
```